# Sincronizar bancos de dados via Webservice C# asp

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, web-service

Tenho bancos de dados no servidor e no cliente e gostaria que as alterações feitas em um sejam enviadas ao outro através de um Webservice.
Por exemplo é adicionado uma nova linha em uma tabela no servidor então é enviada essa nova inserção ao Webservice, que deverá replicar essa ação ao banco de dados do cliente.
Seria possível isso?

OBS: não posso usar um banco de dados no servidor, deve ser de fato um WebService.

Comment: Tem sim uai, depois que você inserir em um manda inserir no outro.
Leia sobre asmx. E esse webService o cliente tem que ler ele do outro lado

Comment: Sua dúvida é apenas se é possível? Ou você está desenvolvendo e existe alguma dúvida pontual?

Comment: Por que Web Service? Use algo mais novo, jovem. Web API, por exemplo.

Comment: A dúvida Renan, é saber se é o Webservice quem fará as inserções no BD dos clientes ou se ele enviará ao cliente as alterações para que o mesmo as faça. Como ele saberá quem são os clientes? Devo ter armazenado todas as informações dos BDs dos clientes no WS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que precisa tomar muito cuidado com a arquitetura. Muita coisa é possível, mas nem tudo é viável ou interessante para você.

**Viabilidade**

Qual o volume de informações que você vai mandar pra um sistema externo? Se o volume é grande, as vezes não é viável formatar tudo com XML. Por isso existe replicação de banco de dados, computadores em redes protegidas etc. Você pode achar que o volume é pequeno, mas precisa tomar cuidado. Operações pequenas nem sempre são fáceis replicar. É fácil mandar *linhas novas* numa inseridas numa tabela de cadastro. Mas se você tem uma tabela de *saldo* de contas de clientes, atualizadas todo dia, vai ter que mandar a tabela inteira todo dia.

**Arquitetura**

Também você precisa pensar a arquitetura. **Enviar** os dados não significa que você precisa ser ativo. Você pode ser um integrador **passivo**.

Por exemplo, você pode ter tabelas que cadastram quem são os clientes que podem pegar informações suas com um token/chave de segurança. De X em X tempo *o cliente* acessa um webservice na sua aplicação com esse token e sua aplicação avisa se tem dados para integrar.

Daí você cria tabelas de controle, para cada cliente, qual foi o último registro integrado etc. E aí você manda um conjunto de registros desde a última vez que ele perguntou. Pode pedir também para ele mandar o último código que ele conseguiu fazer as inserções com sucesso (uma data por exemplo). Mas daí você precisa colocar campos em todo o banco (das tabelas que quer integrar) com datas de atualização para garantir que mandará sempre tudo certinho.

Mesmo assim, sempre mande paginado. Não deixe acumular muita informação.

Vantagens do modo passivo:

- Você cria um protocolo dos seus dados. Se uma empresa externa a sua quiser acessar, você não correrá o risco de cada uma publicar um webservice com um nome ligeiramente diferente, um em java outro em C#, com alguns problemas de integração que você vai ser o responsável em tratar. Se eles precisam acessar, eles acessam e pronto.
- Se houver falhas constantes na comunicação, pode ser que o cliente responsabilize diretamente a sua implementação, mesmo que a falha for do lado do cliente. Quando você garante que pode entregar os dados e conseguir recuperar mostrando ao cliente, muito dificilmente você precisará ter muitas dores de cabeça toda vez que cair a integração

**Informação**

O seu webservice sempre expõe dados. Se você quer mandar algo ativamente, precisa que o cliente exponha um webservice para você. Aí ele que precisa implementar as rotinas de inserção na base dele. O mesmo vale para o modo passivo. Você pode mandar as informações sempre que ele perguntar por elas, mas ele sempre será o responsável em como armazená-las.

**Dica**

Se você está criando o cliente e servidor, use o modo passivo sempre que possível. Mas antes de tudo, considere muito bem a possibilidade de replicação de dados pelo banco quando o volume for alto.