# Replicação entre MySql e Sqlite (E vice-versa)

Tags: android, mysql, web-service, replicação

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que integro um banco MySQL com uma aplicação Android (por meio de um *webservice*). Já consigo fazer conexão, passar dados, altera-los no banco através do App e coisas do gênero.

O meu problema está sendo no momento que preciso fazer uma replicação entre as bases.

Exemplo: Se eu já tiver carregado uma lista no app com o nome e o número de um cliente e precisar alterar o número lá no banco, essa alteração não vem para o aplicativo. A não ser que eu recrie o banco no aplicativo. (Espero estar conseguindo ser claro).

Pesquisei mas não achei nada de útil, queria apenas uma sugestão de como fazer, se alguém já fez algo parecido, simplesmente o caminho 'melhor caminho' para resolver isso.

Comment: Pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44549/6077

Comment: Seu problema seria que as alterações em seu banco remoto não estão replicando no seu app ou o contrário? Isso não ficou muito claro.

Comment: Você não precisa recriar o banco no android para atualizar dados. Os dados precisam chegar ao Android de alguma forma. Pode ser um txt com inserts, ou um arquivo .sqlite para leitura e processamento. Aqui utilizamos rotinas de importação manual. Usamos o AsyncTask para baixar os dados, via FTP, ou HTTP. Utilizdo o SQLiteStatements para operações com os bancos, pegando o cursor do arquivo recebido e atualizando na base da APP.

Answer (score 1):

Implementar esse tipo de coisa nunca é simples. Uma primeira sugestão é colocar um timestamp em cada linha, de modo que você tenha como saber a "versão" de cada linha, aí você tem uma base para comparar se a linha no SQLite local está obsoleta em relação a do banco de dados e vice-versa.

Se você armazenar em algum lugar quando foi o momento da última sincronização de cada celular, pode inclusive fazer um SELECT filtrando pelo timestamp (igual ou maior que a última sincronização) e você pega de forma fácil as linhas alteradas, e ficou fácil suportar múltiplos celulares sincronizando ao mesmo tempo.

Um problema mais chato é a questão de remoção de linhas. Se a(s) tabela(s) envolvida(s) nunca remove(m) linhas, ok. Se removem, é preciso logar (registrar) estas remoções em algum lugar, com o timestamp, para que elas façam parte da atualização recebida pelo celular.

Answer (score 0):

Não há como fazer replicação de forma direta.

É preciso criar um Webservice/API para fazer a comunicação.

Isso é um pouco complexo pois precisa ter um cuidado com o controle da versão dos dados.

Há um framework comercial que se propõe a simplificar esse trabalho: http://sqlite-sync.com/

Também oferece versão gratuita, com limitações referentes ao acesso ao código fonte.